# Should I specify a fill factor on my tables?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a new system with a SQL Server 2005 database which will soon be going into production. A colleague recently mentioned to me that I should always be specifying the fill factor on my tables. Currently I don't specify fill factor on any of my tables.

My application is OLTP with a mix of reads and writes. A couple of my tables are "reference" tables i.e. read-only but most are read-write. The read-only tables are low volume ( < 50000 rows ).

From what I've read in the SQL Server documentation I should be sticking with the default fill-factor unless the table is read only.

Can anyone comment on this, both for read-only and read-write tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't specify a fill factor on your tables. The fill factor is always ignored by the engine, except for one and only one operation: index *build* (which includes initial build of an index on a *populated* table and/or a *rebuild* of an index). So the fill factor makes sense to be specified only in the `ALTER TABLE ...  REBUILD` and `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` operations.

See also [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (25/30) fill factor](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%282530%29-fill-factor.aspx).

Comment: from the link above: The fill-factor setting applies only when the index is created, or rebuilt.

Comment: Does this not imply that I need to specify a fill factor when initially creating my indexes?

Comment: If you create a new index on an existing table *with data in it*. When you create a new table the fill factor has no data to apply to, so it will be ignored.

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify the issue of create empty vs. build/rebuild an index.

Comment: FILLFACTOR is something I've always pretty much ignored, but having to look into it now and finding this surprising. Is this still the case?